# How to get the photo info on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of shares photos in a album.
https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM-ID/photos 
But this info not appear. This is possible?
Where found the potho-id?

Comment: From `facebook Graph API` album https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/   
and picture https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
says you can get `like` but no information `share` count

Comment: it seems there is no way, if there was then i would be in those pages

Comment: it's a shame, the statistics of the post I can not get?